# Referring to multiple files of the same name that have a space in it in Command Prompt

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, code

A project asks me to move files that start with "Econ Project" to another location on the directory.

I have tried
`move "Econ Project*.*\"  ECON\Projects`
`move *"Econ Project".*\  ECON\Projects` and many iterations alike to almost no avail.

Can someone fill me in on the correct method to referring multiple files with that start with the same name and that has a space in it? I have tried searching the web for an answer but came up short.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your current file's folder is "curr", and the name of a file(s) starts with "Econ Projects":

```
cd "path\to\destination folder"
move "C:\Absolute Path\or relative path\curr\Econ Projects*"
```